# Kubernetes Helm bash command : bash: {"message":: command not found

Tags: bash, curl, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to run a curl command in my helm chart that triggers a lambda. If I run my lambda on localhost and hit it with a curl from command line then it works perfectly. However, if I deploy the lambda and try to hit it the way it would work on production, by running through my helm chart, it breaks with the following error :

bash: {"message":: command not found

Here is the helm chart I created:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: clean-receiver-list
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: check-author
        image: "{{ .Values.global.utils.repository }}:{{ .Values.global.utils.imageTag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.global.utils.pullPolicy }}
        command: ['bash', '-c', 'while [ $(curl -sw "%{http_code}" "http://{{ .Release.Name }}-stuff/healthcheck" -o /dev/null) -ne 200 ]; do sleep 15; done' ]
      containers:
        - name: clean-receiver-list
          image: "{{ .Values.global.utils.repository }}:{{ .Values.global.utils.imageTag }}"
          command: ['bash',  '-c', '$(curl -d {"podNamespace": "{{ .Release.Name }}"} "https://mylambda/runTask")']
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

So it is the second curl command with my deployed lambda that is breaking.

Comment: You're using `$(...)` subcommand syntax to run `curl` and then interpret its results as a shell command.  Is that what you expect; or do you just need to HTTP POST to that URL, expecting a JSON body back?

Comment: I'm posting to the endpoint and expecting JSON back

Comment: As Dave Maze suggested, you don't need the $() syntax. It also looks like have an issue with you quotations after curl -d also. The first { will need to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking the command as

```sh
bash -c $(curl ...)
```

which runs the `curl` command; but since it's wrapped inside `$(...)`, it takes the response from that and tries to run it as a shell command.  If the URL you're posting to returns a JSON body, this will produce an error very much like what you're seeing.

The easiest answer is to remove the `$(...)` around the command:

```yaml
command: ['bash',  '-c', 'curl -d {"podNamespace": "{{ .Release.Name }}"} "https://mylambda/runTask"']
```

However, you're not doing anything in this command that actually requires a shell (environment variable expansion, command substitution, running multiple commands, ...) and skipping the shell-wrapper layer might be an improvement.  In particular there are quoting problems that this avoids (is your current form getting an HTTP error because the shell is swallowing the double quotes, so the POST body isn't valid JSON?).  I might write instead:

```yaml
command:
  - curl
  - -d
  # Using YAML "block scalar" syntax to avoid quoting problems
  - >-
      {"podNamespace": "{{ .Release.Name }}"}
  - https://mylambda/runTask
```